# Etymology of the name Quinjet?

Tags: marvel, avengers, etymology

In the *Marvel* universes, the Avengers' jets are Quinjets.  What's the etymology of this name?  Does this refer to someone in the universe?  Or a comic book creator?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The etymology of the name of the legendary Avengers craft comes from its design specifications:**

The quinjet first appeared in The Avengers #61 (February 1969) and was designed by the Wakanda Design Group, headed by the Black Panther, T'Challa. Each one is equipped with VTOL capability and **five turbojet** engines. A quinjet can reach Mach 2.1. Two highly specialized ultra-large Quinjets were used to transport various superheroes through space in the Infinity Crusade mini-series.

The five turbojet engines are the rationale for Quin-Jet.

- quint: [French quinte, from Old French, interval of a fifth (in music), feminine of quint, fifth, from Latin quntus; see penkwe in Indo-European roots.]

[image: image of Quinjet schematic]

Comment: Doesn't the image indicate there are only 4 engines? (label in the bottom-right)

Comment: @Keen - going only off the design drawing, the afterburner would be #5

Comment: An [afterburner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afterburner) is not a separate engine, it's part of the engine design used to drastically increase thrust at the cost of efficiency. There are five engines marked - four in the bottom right and one roughly top center. Only one engine is equipped with an afterburner.

Comment: *Canopy Eternal Release Handle* -- Does that mean the canopy can never be reattached once it's eternally released?

Comment: It's funny, I always thought it was "Queenjet" while watching the avengers animated series.

Comment: Note that three-engine commercial jet airliners appeared in the early '60s and were often referred to as *trijets*; [the quinjet made its first appearance in Avengers #61 in 1969](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Quinjet). Presumably Roy Thomas thought a quinjet would be 66% cooler than a trijet.

Answer (score -2):

So has anyone else realize that the Quinjet name come from boat propulsion.  HamiltonJet pioneered the commercial development of the modern waterjet system in the early 1950’s.[image]

Comment: The name is similar, do you have any evidence at all that it is actually inspired by that? If so please [edit] it into your answer.